# Merging or combining the dimensions of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've got this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Browser] => Chrome
            [Number_Browser] => 3
            [Platform] => MacOSX
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Browser] => Default Browser
            [Number_Browser] => 10187
            [Platform] => unknown
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Browser] => Chrome
            [Number_Browser] => 2
            [Platform] => MacOSX
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Browser] => Chrome
            [Number_Browser] => 1
            [Platform] => MacOSX
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Browser] => Chrome
            [Number_Browser] => 2
            [Platform] => MacOSX
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [Browser] => Chrome
            [Number_Browser] => 1
            [Platform] => MacOSX
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [Browser] => Chrome
            [Number_Browser] => 1
            [Platform] => MacOSX
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [Browser] => Default Browser
            [Number_Browser] => 1
            [Platform] => unknown
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [Browser] => Chrome
            [Number_Browser] => 4
            [Platform] => MacOSX
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [Browser] => Safari
            [Number_Browser] => 1
            [Platform] => MacOSX
        )

)
```

This is what I need to get as a result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Browser] => Chrome
            [Number_Browser] => 14
            [Platform] => MacOSX
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Browser] => Default Browser
            [Number_Browser] => 10188
            [Platform] => unknown
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Browser] => Safari
            [Number_Browser] => 1
            [Platform] => MacOSX
        )

)
```

I've been trying for a while with no luck. I need to combine the sub dimensions so when displaying the list on screen it displays the correct amount.

This data is coming from DB, which in Browser we get the User agent, so that's why there are a number of Chrome in the result because of different versions or User Agent string.

Then I'm using browser cap to make it easier to understand to the end user.

I would like then to combine the arrays so it give me the result as described above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)

Comment: [Using `array_unique()` with multidimensional arrays](http://phpdevblog.niknovo.com/2009/01/using-array-unique-with-multidimensional-arrays.html)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, I trie the flatten methods described on that post but they do not give me the expected result. Not looking to flatten it but to combine the sub dimensions with the same key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can try using `foreach()`. Use an temporary array to set calculation results. Example:

```
$your_arr = Array
(
Array
(
    "Browser" => "Chrome",
    "Number_Browser" => 3,
    "Platform" => "MacOSX",
),

Array
(
    "Browser" => "Default Browser",
    "Number_Browser" => 3,
    "Platform" => "MacOSX",
),

Array
(
    "Browser" => "Chrome",
    "Number_Browser" => 3,
    "Platform" => "MacOSX",
),
//...............
);


$newArr = array();
foreach($your_arr as $key=>$val){
    $index = $val['Browser'];
    if(isset($newArr[$index])){
        $val_0 = $newArr[$index]['Number_Browser'] + $val['Number_Browser'];
        $newArr[$index] = array('Browser'=>$val['Browser'], "Number_Browser" => $val_0, 'Platform'=>$val['Platform']);
    }else{
        $newArr[$index] = $val;
    }
}
$result = array_values($newArr);

print '<pre>';
print_r($result);
print '</pre>';
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for!